# jQuery removeClass from button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove "disabled" class from button when there is at least one char in the input. This is jQuery code:

```
$('.reply').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        $(".replyBtn").removeClass('disabled');
    }
});
```

This is HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="reply" class="reply form-control" placeholder="Rašykite atsakymą...">
<br>
<button type="submit" class="replyBtn btn btn-success disabled">Atsakyti</button>
```

But it's not working and I don't get errors in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.reply').on('input', function() {
  if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    $(".replyBtn").removeClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $(".replyBtn").addClass('disabled');
  }
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="reply" class="reply form-control" placeholder="Rašykite atsakymą...">
<br>
<button type="submit" class="replyBtn btn btn-success disabled">Atsakyti</button>
```

Use `input`